# Imputing NA with conditional LOCF

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, na, locf

I've updated a new different problem. This time I would like to obtain column Oxy2 from Oxy.

```
ID Oxy  Y   Oxy2
1  NA 2010   NA
1   0 2011    0
1  NA 2012   NA
1   1 2013    1
1  NA 2014    1
1  NA 2015    1
1  -1 2016    1
2   0 2011    0
2  NA 2012   NA
2   1 2013    1
2  -1 2014    1
3   0 2012    0
3  -1 2013   -1
3  NA 2014   NA
4  -1 2010   -1
4   1 2011    1
4  -1 2012    1
4  -1 2013    1
4   0 2014    1
4  NA 2015    1
```

Basically, I need to keep NAs, if there any, when previous values of my Oxy variable are 0 or -1, and replace everything coming after the first 1 appears with 1.

Again, thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(Ins1=na.locf(ifelse(is.na(Ins) & lag(Ins)==0, 999, Ins), na.rm = FALSE), Ins2=na_if(Ins1, 999))
   #one step version
   #mutate(Ins1 = na_if(na.locf(ifelse(is.na(Ins) & lag(Ins)==0, 999, Ins), na.rm = FALSE), 999))

# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID   Ins     Y  Ins1  Ins2
  <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0  2010     0     0
2     1    NA  2011   999    NA
3     1     1  2012     1     1
4     1    NA  2013     1     1
5     1    NA  2014     1     1
6     2     0  2011     0     0
7     2     0  2012     0     0
8     2    NA  2013   999    NA
```

Update: To solve the -1 issue, I add a small change to what @user12492692 has suggested in the Edit, namely replaced the `|` with `%in%`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Ins1 = na.locf(ifelse(is.na(Ins) & lag(Ins) %in% c(0,-1), 999, Ins), na.rm = FALSE), 
         Ins2 = na_if(Ins1, 999))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @A.Suliman for your reply. Actually there might be some ID that could have missing INS at start. It gives me the following error "Column Ins1 must be length 10 (the group size) or one, not 9"

Comment: @user:8467042, Can you help me again?

Comment: @user12492692 I think it's better to ask a new question. Provide the link and I'll look at it.

Comment: @user8467042 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275742/conditional-imputation-with-locf

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative that fills all values using the LOCF and then adds NA's following the zeros:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(Ins_b = Ins[!is.na(Ins)][cumsum(!is.na(Ins))],
         Ins_b = replace(Ins_b, is.na(Ins) & Ins_b == 0, NA))

  ID Ins    Y Ins_b
1  1   0 2010     0
2  1  NA 2011    NA
3  1   1 2012     1
4  1  NA 2013     1
5  1  NA 2014     1
6  2   0 2011     0
7  2   0 2012     0
8  2  NA 2013    NA
```

Comment: Thks @Andrew for your nice solution. It worked but failed for those observation having first Ins as NA (which should remain NA).

Comment: @user12492692, do you need to do this by group?

Comment: Yes @Andrew, always by group (ID) sorted by year.